# Session data not saved in plugin controller October CMS

Tags: laravel, session, flash, request, octobercms

In October CMS on the next request the session does not contain data previously set.

**What I did is:**
I am trying to use an action method of a plugin controller in October CMS to put data in the session.

```
\Session::put('name', 'Test Name');
\Session::keep(['name']);
var_dump(\Session::get('name'));
```

After that I redirect to a specific page of my application

```
return \Redirect::to('/created');
```

In this page a component is loaded which is supposed to display data.
However when I try to access the session data in the back-end of this component

```
var_dump(\Session::get('name')); echo '<br>';
```

the session does not contain the data I'd put previously at all.

**I already**

1. Checked whether the *'/storage/framework/sessions'* folder is writable.
2. Whether the session has started.
3. Checked whether there are no other requests between the controller action and the next page (component).
4. Set a longer session lifetime.
5. Checked whether it is 'the correct' session and it is since it contains data set by middleware.
6. Also tried to add flash messages with both:

```
session()->flash("message", "Registered successfully");
```

or

```
\Flash::success('Settings successfully saved!');
```

or

```
return \Redirect::to('/created')->with('message', 'Registered successfully');
```

I have my controller class in the following folder structure:
[Plugin controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkGBb.png)

And the action method looks as following:

```
  public function create(\HttpRequest $request)
  {
    // When robot
    if($request->input("recaptcha") != "success") {
      // Sets a successful message
      session()->flash("message", "Registered successfully");
      session()->flash("status", "Success");
      session()->flash("alert-class", "alert-success");
      \Session::put('name', 'Test Name');
    }
    return \Redirect::to('/created');
  }
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: can you share information about your `action method of a plugin controller` with code  :)

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I added the plugin controller folder structure and the specific controller action method.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I feel like there is something with my (flash) session since when returning with ```return \Redirect::back()->withInput($request->all());``` I am also not able to request the old input data using ```value="{{ form_value('fname') }}"```

Answer (score 1):

I know this response is late, but I had the exact same issue and after many attempts, I found out the issue. You have to group your routes inside `web` middleware as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```